# Fixing an issue with video overlapping in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, html5-video

When animating a fullscreen video background, I found that if two `<video>` tags overlap, while translated with a `transform`, in Chrome on OSX, the one under becomes darker. It's working perfectly in other browsers and on Chrome for Windows.

```css
video {
  width: 640px;
  height: 320px;
  display: block;
}

.top {
  position:relative;
  transform: translate(0,0);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.bottom {
  position:relative;
  transform: translate(0,10px);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.over:checked ~ .top {
  transform: translate(0, 10%);
}
```

```html
Over <input class="over" type="checkbox">
<video class="top" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
<video class="bottom" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

I've recreated the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/2angdzzy/

Is there any workaround for this problem, or has any of you seen or fixed this issue ?

Comment: Good idea, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange issue indeed. I've found out that if you change the video file format to `ogg`, this does not happened. Perhaps you should try other [HTML supported media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) for further investigation.

Here's your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qjwe2ccn/).

Nevertheless, the best way to include an [HTML video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) is with multiple formats for better compatibility.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I removed the alternate versions in the example to simplify the issue, but this seems to fix the problem for now, thanks !